# What are the implications of doing fastboot erase modemst1?

Tags: cyanogenmod, gps, fastboot, motorola-moto-g2

I installed a Cyanogenmod 12.1 snapshot on my Moto G 2014 when I got it, it previously has only had the stock ROM installed, no other custom ROMs. I soon discovered that the GPS wasn't working on Cyanogenmod, some searching quickly revealed that this is a known problem. Because I don't use GPS very often and because I haven't really needed it yet, it didn't really bother me too much and I was hoping it would get fixed in a future update. Today I discovered that there apparently is a fix for this issue, namely executing:

```
fastboot erase modemst1
fastboot erase modemst2
```

in bootloader mode. ([Known issues with CM for the Moto G 2014](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Known_Issues_page_for_titan)) Apparently this erases 2 partitions, my question is, doesn't erasing these partitions have any implications? Wouldn't I remove the firmware of the modem? Don't I have to replace the contents of these partitions with some other image? The instructions in the XDA thread that the CM wiki page links to don't mention anything about the above. I am a bit reluctant to run these commands as my G 2014 has been working perfectly for months now and I've got everything set up, I'm not interested reflashing currently. I have already searched the web about this but I didn't find much, except for some guy with an Xiaomi device who did the same thing resulting in the phone saying the IMEI number was unknown.

Comment: It appears that my caution was a rather good idea...: [Reddit - Moto G getting no service after erase modem partitions](https://www.reddit.com/r/MotoG/comments/2w8f2r/old_moto_g_getting_no_service_after_erasing/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up taking the risk after all other "fix GPS" methods failed and I can report that it was successful and to my knowledge had no side effects, like the ones reported with other devices.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me. After first boot mobile data was not working (but phone was working). After a second reboot also mobile data working.

Moto G falcon
Android 4.4.4

Comment: Double reboot necessary for me on a Moto G7 Power - Motorola must really like the double reboot.

Comment: In order to get my Moto G4 Play (`harpia`) to recognize a new SIM, I too have had to erase my `modemst1`/`2` partitions. I did it via the [TWRP recovery](https://twrp.me/) console, by running `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/modemst1`, and then the same for `modemst2`.